# Write a sed script with custom options and behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to write a joke, which will likely have the format `cat filename | sed "custom words" -`.

How can I invoke `sed` with only the words I want as `"custom words"` and as few other characters? I know I can pass `s/custom/words/` but am looking for other options.

Specifically, I'd like something along the lines of `sed 'on your'` if possible.

Comment: What effect do you want the sed command to have if any? Have you considered avoiding the [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) ? `sed 'custom words'` works (in GNU sed) without raising any error (is that your goal?) because it starts with `c` (change) which replaces a line by what follows. So would commands starting with `a` (append) or `i` (insert)

Comment: I think it would be most desired if the command did nothing or could be made to have the appearance of doing nothing. As well, I'd like my custom string to start with an 'o', which as far as I can see is not an option listed in the man page.

Comment: `sed '#on your'` will probably be the shortest ex-aequo with others and will do exactly nothing (it's a comment). Plus it looks like an hashtag if you're into that

Comment: Beautiful @Aaron, thanks. I'd accept that comment as an answer if I could

Comment: @Ed Morton I'd like to run the program `sed` but use the string `'on your'` as the arguments, and was looking for the least obtrusive way to do this.

Comment: @EdMorton I believe OP is trying to write a funny sentence that could be parsed without error as a bash pipeline, along the lines of `man unzip & fsck`. The question would probably have been more appropriate on the [PPCG SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Aaron is correct, specifically a reference to the George Harrison lyrics `cat I_got_my_mind | sed '#on you' - `, where the file `I_got_my_mind` has more lyrics in it that will be printed out afterwards by the shell.

Comment: Quite literally I thought it would be entertaining to have a bash script that sounds sorta like some song lyrics. In the song, one of the words is "set" which is a (rough) homophone of `sed`, and so I figured I could get some bash running that has the same words as the lyrics, because it is amusing to me. Thus "I got my mind set on you" (-George Harrision, the artist) >>> `cat I_got_my_mind | sed '#on you' - `. For the sole reason that I find it entertaining.

Comment: And @jsarbour I'd like to reiterate that the question isn't very appropriate for the website, although at least it's not as vulgar as the bash.org sample I linked to; still, you're not asking for help developping code. I suggest you use the [PPCG SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) next time for similar questions, its whole purpose revolves around using languages for esoteric and rarely productive purposes.

Comment: @Aaron I get that link, I still don't really get this question but I'm at peace with that conclusion! Thanks

Comment: @EdMorton ah, yes, I tend to agree with you, but I thought I'd leave the fun aspect to OP's discretion and just answer how to have a `sed` command contain arbitraty words without raising an error. I originally expected something like `[...]that's what she | sed[...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your custom words start with `a`, `c` or `i`, you can use them as-is : the append, change and insert commands will take the rest of the line as parameter. Note that this is only true for GNU sed as POSIXLY those commands' syntax include a backslash and a linefeed.

Otherwise you can use `#` which will make the rest of the line a comment.

For single-words you could also use `:`, which makes the following word a label.